# PHP Image uploading - uniqueness via microtime()

Tags: php, file-upload, unique

If I make the filename of each uploaded file PHPs microtime(), are the risks of a collision realistic? And is there a way to further randomize the filenames?

I'm expecting about 20,000 uploads in about a week. That's 2800/day or 119/hour (assuming even distribution). Does anyone have any experience with assuming microtime to be unique?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to generate random file names in your case is to use [GUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guid). They are great because this algorithm guarantees uniqness of the value even for multiple server. If you are using windows the [`com_create_guid`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php) function is for you. 
Also you can look at [`uniqid`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) function which available for all PHP platforms.

Comment: There are some excellent examples in the comments for uniqid that provide more details and other examples for uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

One common method is to create directories in the format of YYYY/MM/DD/id.jpg. That way you don't run into file system limitations as well.

Comment: Those limitations being files/directory? What are those on an apache linux box?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a huuuuge problem. (kinda paranoid)

Just make a check if exists, if exists, solve the colision (maybe in a while loop until guarantee its unique).

I can't imagine so many file per micro-second.